# Zurb Foundation Two Top Bars

Tags: drop-down-menu, navigation, zurb-foundation, multiple-instances, fluid

I am fairly new to using Zurb so I was wondering if someone could shed some light for me.

http://www.bitandpiecesvape.co.uk/

This is my website currently (not running Zurb). I am trying to remake this in Zurb but I am having trouble creating two top bars.

As you can see in the link I have the 5 links in the dark blue bar under the banner, and then the categories in the lighter blue area below it. How can I make it so that these will display as they do in the link, but on resizing the browser to small they should all compile into a dropdown menu.

I have tried with the code below, and it does work... But the second menu just floats a little below it. I have tried seperating the two menus using a div row class but it stops the whole thing working... Obviously I need it to be on two rows so I can position the second menu properly below it.

I apologise that I can't upload a current version of my Zurb template, but I am running all this offline on my laptop at the moment because I am having trouble with my FTP.

Any thoughts???

Thank you.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #0d233c">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name">
                            <h1>
                                <span class="show-for-small-only"><a href="#"><B>Bitandpieces Vape</B></a></span>
                            </h1>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                        <ul class="left" style='height: 100%'>
                          <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="portfolio/">Shipping & Postage</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="ourteam/">Product Support</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="services/">Contact Us</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="aboutus/">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                        <ul class="left" style='height: 100%'>
                          <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="portfolio/">Shipping & Postage</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="ourteam/">Product Support</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="services/">Contact Us</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="aboutus/">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the two top bars with separate instances of topbar rather than adding sections should solve the issue with the navs stacking properly if that is ultimately what you choose to use for this.

```
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
         <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                    <ul class="left" style='height: 100%'>
                      <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="portfolio/">Shipping & Postage</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="ourteam/">Product Support</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="services/">Contact Us</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="aboutus/">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

            </nav>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">

                    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                    <ul class="left" style='height: 100%'>
                      <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="portfolio/">Shipping & Postage</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="ourteam/">Product Support</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="services/">Contact Us</a></li>
                      <li class="active"><a href="aboutus/">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

            </nav>
```

I would also suggest sticking with the foundation grid system and separating out the top banner section completely in it's own row and avoiding those height:100 styles.  The site will be responsive and behave well as long as you use all of he built in classes for Foundation.